# Invoke Java code from DXL in DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to have a custom Addin menu in DOORS, and want to invoke some JAVA code from there. Is it possible to invoke an executable jar file within DXL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on if you can run it from a command prompt. If you can, then all you need to do is call it with the following command:

```
system('C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\JARFILE.exe')
```

This specific example would run a file from the user's desktop. You may need to reference the file differently depending on where it lives.

For more information, search `system` in the DXL Reference Manual inside of DOORS.